# Storing text() retrieved after a mouseover() event as a variable to be used to query a JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am attempting to query a JSON string dynamically based on a particular element being hovered upon. The elements are P tags which only have text that equals the players' name.

The script (contains the json string):

```
<script>
var statName = "hello";

$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      width: 150,
      position: {my: "center", at: "right", of:".baseball-container"},
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
    $(".players").mouseover(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        var statName = $(this).text();
        alert(statName);

    });
});

$players='{"Player One":{"avg":"400","gp":"2","gs":"2","ab":"5","r":"0","h":"2"},
           "Player Two":{"avg":"500","gp":"2","gs":"0","ab":"2","r":"1","h":"1"}}'

var json = JSON.parse($players);
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<p id="draggable" class="players player-one">Player One</p>
<p id="draggable" class="players player-two">Player Two</p>
```

Dialog box:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Statistics">
 <script>
  document.write(statName);
  document.write(json[statName].avg);
 </script>
</div>
```

Of course the one which appears in the dialog box is "hello" while the "alert" is the correct player name. Is there any way I can either change the first "statName" variable to be the one inside of the function (when the user hovers over that player), or is there a way for me to just define statName based off whatever item is hovered on dynamically.

I tried to write a Javascript function which would return the result of the text() retrieved on mouseover() and store it as a variable but this didn't work for me. At best I got "Object Object" as a result.

---

Essentially I need to turn statName within

```
    $(".players").mouseover(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        statName = $(this).text();

    });
```

into a global variable I can use later in the page.

Comment: Don't declare `var statName` again. Just assign values to it. Also there are better ways to fill the dialog if you re using jQuery, instead of using `document.write(..`

Comment: `alert(json[statName].avg)` should work.

Comment: These answers do not work. The issue is the statName var is hidden inside of a function, so it isn't being recognized. I need the var statName within the mouseover function to take over the 'global' variable statName, not just be insulated within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script inside the dialog is executed only the first time the dialog is created.

I suggets you to change a bit:

```js
$(function () {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    width: 150,
    position: {my: "center", at: "right", of:".baseball-container"},
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });
  $(".players").mouseover(function() {
    $('#statName').text(this.textContent);
    $('#avg').text(json[this.textContent].avg);
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );

  });
  $players='{"Player One":{"avg":"400","gp":"2","gs":"2","ab":"5","r":"0","h":"2"},\
"Player Two":{"avg":"500","gp":"2","gs":"0","ab":"2","r":"1","h":"1"}}'
var json = JSON.parse($players);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="baseball-container">
    <p id="draggable1" class="players player-one">Player One</p>
    <p id="draggable2" class="players player-two">Player Two</p>
    <div id="dialog" title="Statistics">
        <p id="statName"></p>
        <p id="avg"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good... I will give it a look and get back to you... thanks for the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog information is getting filled in before your `mouseover` event happens.  During your `mouseover` event handler, you'll need to copy the appropriate information to the dialog.

Which means your dialog could look something like this:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>Avg: <span id="statavg"></span></p>
</div>
```

And your `mouseover` event handler would look like this:

```
$(".players").mouseover(function() {
    playerName = $(this).text();
    $("#statavg").text(json[playerName].avg);
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Though I'm not very familiar with the jQueryUI dialog function.